# Can't Clean Box2D from my Eclipse Android Project

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to Eclipse/Android. I have a cocos2d-x project and have added Box2D based on the responses to http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/20827.

When I do Project/Clean/(Clean all projects) I get

> Clean: box2d_static [armeabi]
>
> rm -rf (TARGET_OBJS)
>
> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

I haven't been able to find the rm -rf (TARGET_OBJS) line in any shell scripts, so I have no idea where this error is coming from.

My hunch is that I may be mixing up a copy of the Box2D source in my project with another copy in the cocos2d-x home folder.

Here is the full build output, followed by the Android.mk for my project.

> 11:19:03 **** Clean-only build of configuration Default for project RacerX ****
>   bash /Users/paul/projects/RacerX/proj.android/build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1 clean
>
> NDK_ROOT = /Users/paul/tools/android-ndk-r8e
>
> COCOS2DX_ROOT = /Users/paul/tools/cocos2d-x-2.1.4
>
> APP_ROOT = /Users/paul/projects/RacerX/proj.android/..
>
> APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /Users/paul/projects/RacerX/proj.android
>
> Using prebuilt externals
>
> make: Entering directory `/Users/paul/projects/RacerX/proj.android'
>
> Clean: box2d_static [armeabi]
>
> rm -rf (TARGET_OBJS)
>
> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>
> make: Leaving directory `/Users/paul/projects/RacerX/proj.android'
>
> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `rm -rf (TARGET_OBJS)'
>
> make: *** [clean-box2d_static-armeabi] Error 2
>
> 11:19:03 Build Finished (took 481ms)

My Android.mk:

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared
>
> LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
>                      ../../Classes/Bike.cpp \
>                      ../../Classes/Terrain.cpp \
>                      ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
>                      ../../Classes/WorldLayer.cpp \
>                      ../../Classes/GLES-Render.cpp
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
>                     ../RacerX/libs/Box2D
>
> LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static
>   cocos_extension_static box2d_static
>                include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
>
> $(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) \ $(call
>   import-module,cocos2dx) \ $(call import-module,external/Box2D) \
>   $(call import-module,extensions)